# What does どうだと言うものでもない mean?

Tags: translation

It's a dialogue from a game. Two girls talk about breast.

> ニーナ:「あー‥アースラさんって意外に‥‥
>
> アースラ:「ふん‥‥ 大きいから　**どうだと言うものでも、ない**がな‥

I know that どうだ means "how; in what way" and と言うものでもない means "doesn't mean that; it's not (true) that; not necessarily", but what is どうだと言うものでもない?

My attempt - they’re big, but it doesn’t mean anything, though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「どう（だ）と言うものでもない」

is a fairly common colloquial phrase meaning:

> "It's nothing special.", "It's no big deal.", etc.

So, it seems you've got the gist of it.

> "Just because my boobs are big, it's no big deal, really."