# grammar of とか言う気だろう

Tags: grammar

I have some difficulty understanding the construction とか言う気だろう

Context: the protagonist is trying to learn a new skill and he is surprised by the move made by his teacher.

> ひょっとして、これが潜伏スキルだ**とか言う気だろう**か。
>
> ... Was that supposed to be the ambush (skill) ?

The part とか言う seems to refer to "something like" (By the way, I do not understand the だ just before)

I have found some hints here

[Meaning of this どうだとか言う construction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60664/meaning-of-this-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8B%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86-construction)

Comment: To understand it better, read it as とか言う+気+だろう. Now とか言うindicates some degree of uncertainty about what's stated before it, that is, これが潜伏スキルだ, and connects the whole phrase as a description of 気. You can read 気 as "intention" here. And again we have だろう which adds yet another degree of supposition/uncertainty. Put it all together with the か and you can see how it is translated as "Was that supposed to be" + the sentence quoted by とか. (note that these are not linguistically-valid terminology, and just used to clear things up)

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment , makes things clear. Now should I close the question, or something else ?

Comment: Don't close it; it's a good question. The first thing to do would be to request that @zareami10 convert the comment to answer. If you get no response then I would recommend adding it as an answer yourself with credit to zareami10 and tick the 'community wiki' box.

Comment: Done as you told me, I was not aware of the community wiki, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With credit to

@zareami10

To understand it better, read it as

> とか言う+気+だろう

Now とか言う　indicates some degree of uncertainty about what's stated before it, that is, これが潜伏スキルだ, and connects the whole phrase as a description of 気. You can read 気 as "intention" here.

And again we have だろう which adds yet another degree of supposition/uncertainty.

Put it all together with the か and you can see how it is translated as "Was that supposed to be" + the sentence quoted by とか. (note that these are not linguistically-valid terminology, and just used to clear things up)