# Help needed breaking down で + なんだっていう in this sentence

Tags: grammar, rhetorical-questions

I have the following sentence from a manga, 「問題集作ったくらいでなんだっていうのよ。そんなの…いらないわ」, and I am not sure what **「でなんだっていう」** is doing here. I think I may be mainly thrown off by the **「で」** at the beginning.

Context:

> 「これ、フータローが私たちのために作ってくれた。 　受け取って」
>
> 「問題集作ったくらいで、なんだっていうのよ。そんなの…いらないわ」

Setting: 5 girls are being tutored and were each given a set of practice problems. One of the girls is upset that she has to complete the practice problems and study, so she is heading upstairs to her room. One of the other girls stops her on the stairs and attempts to hand the test back to her. The girl who is refusing to take the test then (I believe) thinks this sentence in her head. Also worth noting that she has an angry look on her face and is clenching her first.

Here's my attempted breakdown:

> 「問題集作った」 - Made collection of problems
>
> 「くらい」 - degree or extent of how lengthy the set of problems is. (maybe translated as "just")
>
> 「で」  - て form of copula ???
>
> 「なんだっていうの」  - なんだ is explanatory の + copula (the fact is/ the matter is) and っていう is quoting what was introduced before, allowing us to refer to that clause. Then の nominalizes all of this into a noun for us.
>
> 「そんなの」 - literally That kind of thing but meaning something like "c'monn"

So I think she is thinking something like, *"(The fact is) it's just a collection of problems. c'monn"*

Again, I'm not sure what form **「で」** plays in this, so I'm afraid my translation may be off. I'm also not sure if I properly understood what **「くらい」** is doing here either. I think my translation fails to capture the anger she has as well.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55644/9831

Comment: @Chocolate so this is the noun 何 and not the explanatory の as なん? So the sentence would be more so something like "So what if he made those lengthy set of problems!" Of course, I'm still not certain how で works either

Comment: Especially with manga, it's important to see the source to parse it correctly, as most punctuation is omitted. This is 五棟分の花嫁 第039話. It's been transcribed elsewhere as: 「問題集作ったくらいで、なんだっていうのよ。そんなの…いらないわ」.

Comment: @BJCUAI What's this other source?

Comment: http://kokonoi3.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-139.html?sp   I just did a search for "問題集作ったくらいで" and it came up on top.

Comment: For this なんだっていう: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21747/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48967/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56584/7810

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's make it general.

`なんだっていうのよ` has emotional emphasis and woman-specific parts like `よ`. So it'll be like `なんだっていうんだ`, `なんだというのだ`. Or simply `なんだ`.

### Examples

It can be used like

> [少]{すこ}し[外]{そと}を[走]{はし}ったからなんだっていうんだ。その[程度]{ていど}じゃ[痩]{や}せやしないぞ。 (You ran outside a bit? That won't make you slim. / It's not effective to your weight.)
>
> [彼]{かれ}は「[努力]{どりょく}して[解決]{かいけつ}しました」って[言]{い}っていた。それがなんだ。[意味]{いみ}なんてありゃしない。 (He goes like "I've managed to solve it". So what? It's totally nonsense.)

In above cases, the speaker underrates another person's activity. More strongly, despising.

> あの[国]{くに}が[戦争]{せんそう}をしたからといってなんだというのだ。[我々]{われわれ}には[関係]{かんけい}ない。 (We won't care if the country wages a war with another country.)

In this case the speaker has nothing to do with something / is not interested in something.

### The original issue

> [風太郎]{ふうたろう}「(snip)…ただでさえお[前]{まえ}は[出遅]{でおく}れてるんだ、[四人]{よにん}にしっかり[追]{お}いつこうぜ」 (Your score is lower than other sisters. Let's study hard and make it up.)
>
> [二乃]{にの}「うるさいわね。[何]{なに}も[知]{し}らないくせに。とやかく[言]{い}われる[筋合]{すじあ}いはないわ。あんたなんか、ただの[雇]{やと}われ[家庭教師]{かていきょうし}。[部外者]{ぶがいしゃ}よ」 (Shut up. You know nothing and have nothing to do with me. You are just a hired private teacher. An outsider.)
>
> ...
>
> [三玖]{みく}「これ、フータローが[私]{わたし}たちのために作ってくれた。[受]{う}け[取]{と}って」 (Here, Futaro has made it for us. Take this.)
>
> [二乃]{にの}「[問題集]{もんだいしゅう}[作]{つく}ったくらいで、なんだっていうのよ。そんなの…いらないわ」 (He made a question collections... So what? I don't need this.)

Thanks to @BJCUAI, it seems it's from 『[五等分]{ごとうぶん}の[花嫁]{はなよめ}』, a popular manga.

It's hard to translate it in simple sentence. Nino is angry to him (Futaro) and she spat out her emotion at Miku. It's clear that the question collections are useful to study, but Nino won't accept that.